# How to set the machine key to be the same for 2 web applications?

Tags: asp.net, web-config, machinekey

I have 2 web applications where I have to set the machine key to be the same in the web.config.

Where do I get the machine key from?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Machine key generator

http://www.aspnetresources.com/tools/keycreator.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Instructions here for generating machine key through IIS:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/amb/archive/2012/07/31/easiest-way-to-generate-machinekey.aspx

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731979%28v=ws.10%29.aspx